# Using React.cloneElement to override props onChangeText and onSubmitEditing not working when the TextInput is a child of the element

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component that I'm passing into my native npm

```js
    footerInput = {
                  <View>
                    <View style={{backgroundColor: "black", height:1, width:"90%", alignSelf:"center"}} />  
                      <TextInput
                          style={styles.chatInputStyle}
                      />
                    <View style={{backgroundColor: "black", height:1, width:"90%", alignSelf:"center"}} />  
                  </View>
    }
```

Inside of my npm I'm using it like this

```js
      {footerInput && (
        <View style={{marginTop:8}}>
            {React.cloneElement(footerInput, {value:value,
                                              onSubmitEditing:handleSubmitEditing,
                                              onChangeText:text => onChangeValue(text)})}
        </View>
      )}
```

The problem I have is that it only seems to work if the component I'm calling "footerInput" is just a TextInput, when I style it using the above views it never gets a value from onChangeText. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about how `footerInput` is defined, e.g. `<MyComp footerInput={<CustomInput />}` or are you creating the variable somewhere in the component?

Comment: Thanks for looking.  Footer input is the combination of views above. When I have this combination of views/styling I can't seem to get the value/onSubmit/onChange to work. If I define footerInput as simply the TextInput it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `{}` to define a component / elements is not valid syntax, you should use `()`.

```js
const footerInput = (
  <View>
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "black",
        height: 1,
        width: "90%",
        alignSelf: "center",
      }}
    />
    <TextInput style={styles.chatInputStyle} />
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "black",
        height: 1,
        width: "90%",
        alignSelf: "center",
      }}
    />
  </View>
);
```

`React.cloneElement` will only clone the first element, in this case the `View` which wraps all the other elements. The `View` element does not do anything with the props you pass in like `value`.

You could solve this by creating a custom component.

```js
function FooterInput({ value, onSubmitEditing, onChangeText }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "black",
          height: 1,
          width: "90%",
          alignSelf: "center",
        }}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.chatInputStyle}
        value={value}
        onSubmitEditing={handleSubmitEditing}
        onChangeText={(text) => onChangeValue(text)}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "black",
          height: 1,
          width: "90%",
          alignSelf: "center",
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Which you can use like so, instead of `footerInput` you can have a `showFooterInput` state of prop where you can determine to render the input.

```js
function YourComponent() {
  return (
    <View>
      {showFooterInput ? (
        <FooterInput
          value={value}
          onSubmitEditing={handleSubmitEditing}
          onChangeText={(text) => onChangeValue(text)}
        />
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
}
```